# Different color scheme for :after :before selector

Tags: css, background, css-selectors

In my view have a CSS class box, in after and before selector have property background colour.

I need to use the class like "box red" or "box green" and change the colour of after or before selector.

The below code snippet does not contain my full CSS. I hide some transform code for after and before selectors.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding:14px 0 10px 27px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 15%;
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.box:before {
  top: 0;
  // some other line here
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.box:after {
  top: 50%;
  // some other line here
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.box:after, .box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  z-index:-1;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #434c51;
}
```

```html
<div class="box red">Box 1</div>
<div class="box green">Box 2</div>
```

Comment: `:before` and `:after` is deprecated syntax. You should use `::before` and `::after` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.box.green:before, .box.green:after {
  background: green;
}
.box.red:after, .box.red:before {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by applying background to  `.box.red:before`  or `.box.red:after`

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding:14px 0 10px 27px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 15%;
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.box:before {
  top: 0;
  // some other line here
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.box:after {
  top: 50%;
  // some other line here
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.box:after, .box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  z-index:-1;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #434c51;
}
/*Added**/
.box.green:after ,.box.green:before {
    background: green;
}
.box.red:after,.box.red:before {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box red">Box 1</div>
<div class="box green">Box 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the question but, as per my understanding it seems to be a very basic one something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding:14px 0 10px 27px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 15%;
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.box:before {
  top: 0;
  // some other line here
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.box:after {
  top: 50%;
  // some other line here
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.box:after, .box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  z-index:-1;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #434c51;
}

.red:after , .red:before {
content: '';
 background-color: red;

}
.box.green:before, .box.green:after {
  background: green;
}
</style>
<body ng-app="">

Show HTML: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar">

<div class="box red">Box 1</div>
<div class="box green">Box 2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this .box.red:after {}  Or .box.green:after {} 
and your snippet should be :

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding:14px 0 10px 27px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 15%;
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.box:before {
  top: 0;
  // some other line here
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.box:after {
  top: 50%;
  // some other line here
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.box:after, .box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  z-index:-1;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #434c51;
}
.box.red:before,.box.red:after { background:red}
.box.green:before,.box.green:after { background:#5FBA7D}
<!--- or you can use after as you need -->
```

```html
<div class="box red">Box 1</div>
<div class="box green">Box 2</div>
```

Comment: `:before` and `:after` is deprecated syntax. You should use `::before` and `::after` instead.